# Pandoc - HTML to Markdown - How to use "simple table" by default?

Tags: markdown, pandoc

Is there an option or extension in pandoc to o use *simple table* (without column boundaries) by default, i.e, as much as possible, when converting from HTML to markdown?

The current output:

```
| fruit  | price |
|--------|-------|
| apple  | 2.05  |
| pear   | 1.37  |
| orange | 3.09  |
```

The desired output:

```
fruit | price
---|---
apple | 2.05
pear | 1.37
orange | 3.09
```